Odin float conversion in core:encoding/json
When loading values from json, if I parse -10.0 from a json file it doesn't get converted to -10.0 but -9.98..
Is this expected behavior? Is it something to do with floats? When I simply multiply 10 by -1 and save it into f64/f32 it is represented as -10 so it shouldn't be issue in float representation.
I have tested this on a minimal code example
odin compiler version dev-2024-09
And I am on Kubuntu 24.04
package main

import "core:encoding/json"
import "core:fmt"
import "core:os"

main :: proc() {
    data, ok := os.read_entire_file_from_filename("test.json")
    if !ok {
        fmt.println("Data read incorrectly.")
        return
    }
    defer delete(data)

    json_data, err := json.parse(data)
    if err != .None {
        fmt.println("Json couldn't be parsed")
        return
    }
    defer json.destroy_value(json_data)

    root := json_data.(json.Object)
    value := root["val"].(json.Float)

    fmt.println("Value read:", value)

    value_negative_10: f64 = 10.0 * (-1)
    fmt.println("Value real:", value_negative_10)
}

test.json
{
  "val": -10.0
}

Does anyone know that is going on here?
I planned to raise this as a bug, but I thought I ought to ask first if this is how it should be or not.

I know next to nothing about Odin, but nothing jumps out at me here that you could possibly be doing wrong, so I'd be leaning towards filing that bug report as well.

Note: This was indeed a bug and has since been resolved https://github.com/odin-lang/Odin/issues/4361
